Agents unable to enter process flow
agent stuck at stateI have issues with the agents entering into the process flow from the state chart. I followed the Anylogic tutorials and unable to get it to work. Need help on this, please
engine state chart
process flow for serviceable engines to go for mission
each mission utilise only 5 engines, total engines is 20. Hence I placed a queue to ensure only 5 goes into the mission segment
Help to resolve why the agents are not moving through the process flow. It got stuck at the MoveToMission state.

what you did is fine and should work. But you were smart when you decided not to show us what problems you encounter. This way we can guess. We love guessing games here.

Actually there isn't any error message popping out. It just gets stuck and not moving.


Help to resolve why the agents are not moving through the process flow. It got stuck at the MoveToMission state.

Then your agent is never reaching its target from the moveTo call in moveToMission.
Ensure it can and does move, and the transition will trigger
